# ElasticSearch - Search analyzed and not_analyzed multi_field in one query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an indexed field 'properties.language' with the value 'en sv'. This field has a multi_field mapping that consists of two fields, one analyzed (name 'language'), and one that is not_analyzed (name '_exact').

How do I issue a single search query without having to query both 'properties.language' and 'properties.language._exact'?

**Edit:**

Here is my configuration:

Indexed data:

```
{
    "_index": "51ded0be98035",
    "_type": "user",
    "_id": "WUzwcwhTRbKur7J5ZY_hgA",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "properties": {
            "language":"en sv"
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping for type 'user':

```
{
    "user": {
        "properties": {
            "properties": {
                "properties": {
                    "language": {
                        "type": "multi_field",
                        "fields": {
                            "language": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "analyzer": "standard",
                                "index": "analyzed"
                            },
                            "_exact": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Search query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "or": [{
                            "term": {
                                "properties.language": "en sv"
                            }
                        }, {
                            "term": {
                                "properties.language._exact": "en sv"
                            }
                        }]
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your settings (analyzers), mappings and queries? It's difficult to tell what kind of results you're looking to achieve only by description.

Comment: So you always want to match on exactly `en sv` then? If so, then you only need to do a must match on your `_exact` field. Although, I'm guessing that's not the issue you're having... I'm confused what you're actually trying to accomplish in your query.

Comment: No, I would like to be able to match on both the analyzed and the exact text. But I don't want to specify both in the query. I.e. the following queries should match: ['en sv', 'sv', 'en']. I would also like a wildcard search on the exact text, but that is a different question...

Comment: I'm struggling to see why you need to have exact matching for anything (except the wildcard), unless you have not given us all your requirements. If you just use a bog-standard mapping and send 'ev sv' to it. the queries ['en sv', 'sv', 'en'] will all match. Then use the not_analyzed version for wildcard stuff. Though there are much faster ways to do wildcard-like search.

Answer (score 3):

Consider indexing the `language` field using Elasticsearch builtin multi-valued fields (ie. arrays) instead: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/array-type/. As you currently do, set `index` to `not_analyzed`.

When indexing your data, instead of a single value `'en sv'`, pass instead `['en', 'sv']`, and ES will take care of the rest.

For querying, this gives you the ability to do the following to find items with both `en` and `sv`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match_all": {}
            },
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "term": {
                            "properties.language": "en"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "term": {
                            "properties.language": "sv"
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or even better, find greater brevity/flexibility using the `terms` query/filter instead of `term`: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/terms-query/