# Elasticsearch wildcard search on not_analyzed field

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch, tokenize

I have an index like following settings and mapping;

```
{
  "settings":{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "analyzer_keyword":{
                 "tokenizer":"keyword",
                 "filter":"lowercase"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "mappings":{
     "product":{
        "properties":{
           "name":{
              "analyzer":"analyzer_keyword",
              "type":"string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

I am struggling with making an implementation for wildcard search on `name` field. My example data like this;

```
[
{"name": "SVF-123"},
{"name": "SVF-234"}
]
```

When I perform following query;

```
http://localhost:9200/my_index/product/_search -d '
{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "query_string" : {
                    "query": "*SVF-1*"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}'
```

It returns `SVF-123`,`SVF-234`. I think, it still tokenizes data. It must return only `SVF-123`.

Could you please help on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI,you really don't want a leading wildcard, I think it will look at every doc if you do that.

Comment: I know the defect on performance but, I need to perform wildcard search even SVF-*

Comment: I think trailing wildcards is fine, you just dont want the leading one..

Comment: When user VF, IT should return SVF-... that is why I used leading wildcard

Comment: I think the best practice is to use [reverse token](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-reverse-tokenfilter.html) so that leading wildcards can become trailing wildcards.

Comment: Have you got any working example or gist?

Comment: If you have a leading wildcard (e.g. `*tastic`) you want to index e.g. "citsatnaf" (by reversing "fantastic") so you can search for `citsat*`. A search engine can easily find terms given its prefix. Here's more information: http://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**My solution adventure**

I have started my case as you can see in my question. Whenever, I have changed a part of my settings, one part started to work, but another part stop working. Let me give my solution history:

**1.)** I have indexed my data as default. This means, my data is `analyzed` as default. This will cause problem on my side. For example;

When user started to search a keyword like **SVF-1**, system run this query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "query_string" : {
                    "analyze_wildcard": true,
                    "query": "*SVF-1*"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and results;

```
SVF-123
SVF-234
```

This is normal, because `name` field of my documents are `analyzed`. This splits query into tokens `SVF` and `1`, and `SVF` matches my documents, although `1` does not match. I have skipped this way. I have create a mapping for my fields make them `not_analyzed`

```
{
  "mappings":{
     "product":{
        "properties":{
           "name":{
              "type":"string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           },
           "site":{
              "type":"string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           } 
        }
     }
  }
}
```

but my problem continued.

**2.)** I wanted to try another way after lots of research. Decided to use [wildcard query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html).
My query is;

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : {
            "name" : {
                "value" : *SVF-1*"
             }
          }
      },
            "filter":{
                    "term": {"site":"pro_en_GB"}
            }
    }
}
```

This query worked, but one problem here. My fields are not_analyzed anymore, and I am making wildcard query. Case sensitivity is problem here. If I search like **svf-1**, it returns nothing. Since, user can input lowercase version of query.

**3.)** I have changed my document structure to;

```
{
  "mappings":{
     "product":{
        "properties":{
           "name":{
              "type":"string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           },
           "nameLowerCase":{
              "type":"string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           }
           "site":{
              "type":"string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
           } 
        }
     }
  }
}
```

I have adde one more field for `name` called `nameLowerCase`. When I am indexing my document, I am setting my document like;

```
{
    name: "SVF-123",
    nameLowerCase: "svf-123",
    site: "pro_en_GB"
}
```

Here, I am converting query keyword to lowercase and make search operation on new `nameLowerCase` index. And displaying `name` field.

Final version of my query is;

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : {
            "nameLowerCase" : {
                "value" : "*svf-1*"
             }
          }
      },
            "filter":{
                    "term": {"site":"pro_en_GB"}
            }
    }
}
```

Now it works. There is also one way to solve this problem by using [multi_field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926572/elasticsearch-search-analyzed-and-not-analyzed-multi-field-in-one-query). My query contains dash(-), and faced some problems.

Lots of thanks to @Alex Brasetvik for his detailed explanation and effort

Answer (score 15):

There's a couple of things going wrong here.

First, you are saying that you don't want terms analyzed index time. Then, there's an analyzer configured (that's used search time) that generates incompatible terms. (They are lowercased)

By default, all terms end up in the `_all`-field with the standard analyzer. That is where you end up searching. Since it tokenizes on "-", you end up with an OR of "*SVF" and "1*".

Try to do a terms facet on _all and on name to see what's going on.

Here's a runnable Play and gist: https://www.found.no/play/gist/3e5fcb1b4c41cfc20226 (https://gist.github.com/alexbrasetvik/3e5fcb1b4c41cfc20226)

You need to make sure the terms you index is compatible with what you search for. You probably want to disable `_all`, since it can muddy what's going on.

```
#!/bin/bash

export ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:9200"

# Create indexes

curl -XPUT "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/play" -d '{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "text": [
                "SVF-123",
                "SVF-234"
            ],
            "analyzer": {
                "analyzer_keyword": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "type": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "not_analyzed",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'


# Index documents
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_bulk?refresh=true" -d '
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"name":"SVF-123"}
{"index":{"_index":"play","_type":"type"}}
{"name":"SVF-234"}
'

# Do searches

# See all the generated terms.
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "facets": {
        "name": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "name"
            }
        },
        "_all": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "_all"
            }
        }
    }
}
'

# Analyzed, so no match
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "name": {
                "query": "SVF-123"
            }
        }
    }
}
'

# Not analyzed according to `analyzer_keyword`, so matches. (Note: term, not match)
curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "name": {
                "value": "SVF-123"
            }
        }
    }
}
'


curl -XPOST "$ELASTICSEARCH_ENDPOINT/_search?pretty" -d '
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "_all": {
                "value": "svf"
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Comment: First, thanks for your answer. I have used your examples, but it didn't worked for my case. My case a bit complicated. Finally, I have found a  solution and I will state whole case in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Hüseyin answer, we can use AND as the default operator. So SVF and 1* will be joined using AND operator, therefore giving us the correct results.

```
"query": {
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "query_string" : {
                "default_operator": "AND",
                "analyze_wildcard": true,
                "query": "*SVF-1*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Viduranga Wijesooriya as you stated `"default_operator" : "AND"` will check for presence of both SVF and 1 but exact match alone is still not possible,
but ya this will filter the results in more appropriate way leaving with all combination of SVF and 1 and sorting the results by relevance which will promote SVF-1 up the order

For pulling out the exact result

```
"settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "analyzer_keyword": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "type": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "analyzer_keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and the query is

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {
                    "query_string" : {
                        "fields": ["name"],
                        "query" : "*svf-1*",
                        "analyze_wildcard": true
                    }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

result

```
{
   "took": 4,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 1,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "play",
            "_type": "type",
            "_id": "AVfXzn3oIKphDu1OoMtF",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name": "SVF-123"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```