# Elasticsearch Java api - Select query for searching text mixed with special characters(John-son)

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch

I have two users in my db collection and those names are  `john`  and  `john-son` ,  now I am trying to select all records which are matching with my search text among all fields of db collection. For example my search text is `john`  then my query is by using elasticsearch java api

```
QueryBuilder queryBuilderForUserSearch = QueryBuilders.must(
        QueryBuilders.fieldQuery("_all", "*" + q + "*"));
```

It's working fine. But when I am trying to search with special character text like  `john-son`  by this time it returns zero records. Can anybody please help me why it's happens and please provide the query for select text with special characters also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is largely the same as in this question: [Elasticsearch wildcard search on not_analyzed field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161062/elasticsearch-wildcard-search-on-not-analyzed-field/21164292#21164292)

First, you really don't want to have leading wildcards in your query. Lucene will have to go through every term in your index's dictionary to find terms. This is O(n) in the number of terms, which gets prohibitively expensive. See this article for more details: http://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-from-the-bottom-up/

What's probably happening here is that `john-son` is tokenized to `john` and `son` via the `standard`-analyzer. Therefore, there is no `john-son` term in the dictionary for your wildcard query to match.